# Function 'stof' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw

I had this problem before but found a work around, only this time a work around is not an option.

I'm trying to use the 'stof' function but I'm getting errors saying:
'stof' is not a member of 'std'
Function 'stof' could not be resolved

I'm using it in the exact way if shows on this page:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/

And here are my includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

So, what am I doing wrong? And if a solution cannot be found could someone point me to another way to convert string to float and have it throw an exception if the string was not compatible?

EDIT: Updating with sample program and errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string testString = "";
   float testFloat = 0.0;
   testFloat = std::stof(testString);

   return 0;
}
```

The errors I get are:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
'stof' is not a member of 'std' main.cpp    /Assignment/src line 33 C/C++ Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Function 'stof' could not be resolved   main.cpp    /Assignment/src line 33 Semantic Error

Comment: `std::stof` is new in the C++11 standard.  Are you sure you're using a C++11-compatible compiler?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm not too experienced with C++, but I have "-std=c++11" as one of my commands

Comment: You might also try -stdlib=libc++

Comment: No luck with -stdlib=libc++ Nathan S, thanks anyway

Comment: You're not by chance using MinGW are you?  There's an [open bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52015) that might explain why it's not working for you.

Comment: @JosephLittle It's hard to give any more advice at this point. Please write a minimal example program and tell us exactly how you compile it and the exact error output.

Comment: @Michael Yeah I'm using MinGW, so this could well be the problem.

Comment: @Cubic okay, just let me update the question with it.

Comment: @JosephLittle those errors can't be from the code you posted. You don't have 33 lines in there. Do you use any IDE? If so, make sure that that IDE is actually using the compiler you think it's using (with the right settings).

Comment: Ah sorry, they are from the code, it's just I've got a lot of other #includes commented out while I'm just testing this.
I'm using Eclipse and it's using MinGW (It says so in the build output)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `stof` correctly.  This is a [known bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52015) in the MinGW build of gcc 4.7.2.  It should be fixed for gcc 4.8.  There are numerous examples on SO for converting strings to numbers.  Here's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4669311/46821).  You'll have to roll your own to get the exception behavior you want, but the examples should get you started.

Comment: Ah, that would explain everything then. Do you know of any other way I can convert a string to a float and have it throw an exception if they are not compatible?

Comment: [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.lexical_cast) throws an exception when it fails.

Answer (score 12):

[stof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) is a C++11 function. Make sure your compiler supports it (no compiler has full support for C++11 yet, though most modern compilers out there right now support a fairly large subset).

On g++ for instance you have to enable it with the `-std=c++11` option (`std=c++0x` pre g++-4.7).

If you're using g++, please check which version you're using with `g++ -v` - if it's an old version (like 4.2 for instance) c++11 functionality won't be available.

Comment: I compiled with "-v" and found:
gcc version 4.7.2 (GCC) 
In the build report

Comment: Just tested with gcc 4.7.2, it definitely works both with `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++0x`.